# How to allocate more gumdrop whitelist tokens than the amount of nfts in candy machine?

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v2

I got this error when creating gumdrop using `--claim-integration candy`

```
Error: Distributor is allocated more mints (3376) than the candy machine has remaining (1000)
```

Is there any work around it / bypass?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: This check is valid and is used to make sure all of your users who try to claim their NFT will receive one. Deactivating the check will have side effects like showing your users that they are able to claim but then only claiming a bot tax token since no NFTs are available anymore in your candy machine.

Nevertheless here is how to bypass that check:

1. Go into `packages/cli/src/helpers/gumdrop/claimant.ts`
2. You want to remove the following lines which are currently starting at line 295:

```
if (remaining.lt(total)) {
  throw new Error(
    `Distributor is allocated more mints (${total}) ` +
      `than the candy machine has remaining (${remaining})`,
  );
}
```

**Attention**: The gumdrop UI does not verify if the candy machine still has NFTs available. It will allow your users to try to claim their mint even if the candy machine is sold out. Please modify the Gumdrop UI accordingly to include a check like this prior to minting or your users will pay bot tax!